# mod_wsgi app in two different ports

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I have a WSGI app working in prod and I want a staging app in the same server, So I configured two virtual hosts in different ports, 80 for prod and 9090 for stag, but every time I request port 9090 it is using the prod app and I dont know why. Here is my configuration:

prod.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName dashboard
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dashboard
    WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/dashboard/wsgi.py process-group=dashboard application-group=dashboard
    WSGIPassAuthorization on
    Alias /static/ /srv/dashboard/static/
    Alias /favicon.ico /srv/dashboard/static/favicon.ico

    DocumentRoot "/srv/dashboard"
    <Directory /srv/dashboard>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/dashboard/static>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dashboard-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dashboard-access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

stag.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
Listen 9090
NameVirtualHost *:9090
ServerName dashboard-stagging
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    ServerName dashboard-stagging
    WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard-stagging display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup dashboard-stagging
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/dashboard-stagging/wsgi.py process-group=dashboard-stagging application-group=pnpdash$
    WSGIPassAuthorization on
    Alias /static/ /srv/dashboard-stagging/static/
    Alias /favicon.ico /srv/dashboard-stagging/static/favicon.ico

    DocumentRoot "/srv/dashboard-stagging"
    <Directory /srv/dashboard-stagging>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/dashboard-stagging/static>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dashboard-stag-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dashboard-stag-access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

My /var/log/httpd/dashboard-stag-access.log keeps empty when I request http://dashboard.mycompany.com:9090 and it uses the app in port 80.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie names of your apps called by wsgi (prod and stag), they must not conflict. 
Example: I have 2 apps with flask and wsgi, using the same program with different parameters. I have to assign different values to config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"] to avoid conflicts.